# How to setup displaylink to keep working even after a restart

Tags: elementary-os, displaylink

I have setup display link on my elementary OS, but each time i restart my laptop, seems like all the settings gets reset and i have to reinstall display link to get it working again.

I do however notice some weird logs while i setup display link

executing this command `displaylink-debian/5.6.1/displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run` results in the log below

```
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.6.1-59.184  100%  
Distribution discovered: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Installing
[ Installing EVDI ]
[[ Installing EVDI DKMS module ]]

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/source ->
                 /usr/src/evdi-1.12.0

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-166-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-166-generic/build/include KVERSION=4.15.0-166-generic DKMS_BUILD=1....
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

evdi.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-166-generic/extra/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
[[ Installing module configuration files ]]
[[ Installing EVDI library ]]
make: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp.nWZNY8zKBb/evdi/library'
cc -I../module -std=gnu99 -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o evdi_lib.o evdi_lib.c
cc evdi_lib.o -shared -Wl,-soname,libevdi.so.0 -o libevdi.so.1.12.0 -lc -lgcc 
cp libevdi.so.1.12.0 libevdi.so
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp.nWZNY8zKBb/evdi/library'
[ Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager ]
[ Installing libraries ]
[ Installing firmware packages ]
[ Installing licence file ]
[ Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/4xxx/5xxx/6xxx devices ]
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known
[ Adding upstart and powermanager sctripts ]
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known

Please read the FAQ
http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu

Installation complete!

Please reboot your computer if you're intending to use Xorg.
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known
```

at this point my external monitors start working, but once i restart, i have to start the installation from the very beginning. i suspect the cause for this is somewhere in these logs which keep appearing at the very end

```
logname: no login name
Failed to get session path: No session 'SESSION' known
```

suggestions please

**System Details**

elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Built on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Linux 4.15.0-166-generic

GTK 3.22.30

Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz

Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)

Comment: Hi there, I currently face the same problem on Fedora 37 kernel 6.1.14-200. Did you find a fix? I will keep you updated if I find a solution

Comment: hello, unfortunately not, i did not find a fix yet

Comment: @L.Busekrus did you find a fix?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was using https://github.com/displaylink-rpm/displaylink-rpm, but have now switched to a dock that works without DisplayLink to avoid the inconvenience of Linux + DisplayLink.